# Ошибка: aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse inline keyboard button: can't find field "text"

Tags: python, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot('token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Привет!')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def info(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Создать профиль игрока',))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('Создать профиль стаффа',))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardMarkup('У меня уже есть аккаунт', callback_data='id.pubgm'))
    await message.reply('Добро пожаловать', reply_markup=markup)


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: а кнопки у нас разве указываются как клавиатуры?)

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос. В какой конкретно строке возникает ошибка?